# Runtime configuration for create-react-app

Tags: configuration, create-react-app

Currently create-react-app supports the **.env** file for injecting config into the build.

This process is static as everytime the .env variables change, the project has to be built again.

Is there a way to inject configuration at runtime without rebuilding the project?